# python error handling and exception

Tags: python, error-handling

I have a python code similar to this:

```
def f(x): .....

z = []
for i in range(10):
    z.append(f(i))
```

Now f can return warnings message or stop and return an error.  I would like to ignore the warnings message and return `i` if there is an error in `f(i)`

I have tried :

```
try:
  f(i)
except Exception:
  return(i)
```

but in this case also the warnings are considered errors.

Comment: how are warnings shown? How does the code raise a warning; is it printed to stderr?

Answer (score 0):

If your warnings all derive from the standard `Warning` class, just check if the exception derives from `Warning`:

```
try:
    f(i)
except Exception as e:
    if not isinstance(e, Warning):
        return i
```

Comment: In this way the result would be f(i) even if f(i) returns warnings?

Comment: @Donbeo Well you have to return `f(i)` if you want that.

Comment: but how can I return f(i) in case of warnings and i in case of error?